# Inserindo mensagem de erro ao usuário

Tags: python

Faça um programa que receba dois números. Calcule e mostre: A soma dos números pares desse intervalo, incluindo os números digitados. A multiplicação dos números ímpares desse intervalo, incluindo os digitados.

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
x = int(input('Digite um número: '))
y = int(input('Digite um número: '))


par = 0
impar = 1

for i in range(x-1, y+1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        par = par + i
    elif i % 2 != 0:
        impar = impar * i


print('A soma dos números pares entre', x, 'e', y, 'é', par, '.')
print('A multiplicação dos números impares entre', x, 'e', y, 'é', impar, '.')
```

Porém se o usuário informa o primeiro número maior que o segundo, ou os dois números iguais, o resultado retornado é errado.

Resolvi da seguinte forma.

```
while True:
    x = int(input('Digite um número: '))
    y = int(input('Digite um número: '))
    if x < y:
        break
    else:
        continue

    if x == y:
        break
    else:
        continue


par = 0
impar = 1

for i in range(x-1, y+1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        par = par + i
    elif i % 2 != 0:
        impar = impar * i


print('A soma dos números pares entre', x, 'e', y, 'é', par, '.')
print('A multiplicação dos números impares entre', x, 'e', y, 'é', impar, '.')
```

Porem, Gostaria de colocar uma mensagem de erro, para que o usuário saiba o que tem que fazer.

```
while True:
    x = int(input('Digite um número: '))
    y = int(input('Digite um número: '))
    if x < y:
        "Acredito que aqui deveria estar a mensagem de erro, porem colocando o print com erro aqui não da certo."
        break
    else:
        continue

    if x == y:
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa usar `continue`. Basta colocar o `print` nos casos de erro e só chamar o `break` se não entrar em nenhum desses casos:

```
while True:
    x = int(input('Digite um número: '))
    y = int(input('Digite um número: '))
    if x == y: # se forem iguais
        print('Números não podem ser iguais')
    elif x > y: # se x for maior que y
        print('x deve ser menor que y')
    else: # x é menor que y, sai do loop
        break
```

Se forem iguais, imprime a primeira mensagem. Se `x` for maior que `y`, imprime a segunda mensagem. Senão, sai do *loop*.

Nesse caso, se cai em um dos casos de erro, o `while` continua executando e ele pede que os números sejam digitados novamente. Mas se a ideia for sair do programa, você pode usar [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

```
import sys
x = int(input('Digite um número: '))
y = int(input('Digite um número: '))
if x == y:
    print('Números não podem ser iguais')
    sys.exit(1)
elif x > y:
    print('x deve ser menor que y')
    sys.exit(2)
```

O número passado para `sys.exit` é opcional (se nenhum for passado, será zero), e é geralmente usado para indicar o código de erro (eu usei códigos diferentes para indicar cada situação).

E nesse caso, nem precisa de *loop*, já que ou o programa é encerrado, ou ele prossegue (não há o "tente novamente").

---

Outro detalhe é que se você quer os números entre `x` e `y` (com `y` incluso), então deve usar `range(x, y + 1)`.

E o seu `for` não precisa do `elif`, podendo ser trocado por `else`:

```
soma_pares = 0
produto_impares = 1
for i in range(x, y + 1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        soma_pares += i
    else:
        produto_impares *= i
```

Isso porque se `i % 2` for zero, entra no `if`. Se não entrou no `if`, que dizer que com certeza não é zero, então no `else` eu não preciso testar se é diferente de zero (nesse ponto fazer `elif i % 2 != 0` é redundante e desnecessário).

Também usei `+=` (que já soma e atribui o resultado à variável) e `*=` (que faz o mesmo com a multiplicação), e dei nomes melhores para as variáveis. Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

---

Por fim, vale lembrar que [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) dá erro se não for digitado um número válido. Se quiser validar isso, uma alternativa é:

```
def ler_numero(mensagem='Digite um número'):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(mensagem))
        except ValueError:
            print('Não foi digitado um número válido')

x = ler_numero()
y = ler_numero()
```

Assim, a função fica tentando converter o que foi digitado para número. Se não der certo, é lançado o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) e ele pede que digite novamente.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tentar usar a função "try" e "except", caso o "try" dê errado, a função "except" entrará em jogo printando o que você quiser na tela, o except também tem alguns argumentos que ele só ativa caso o erro seja por exemplo "ValueError", aconselho você a dar uma pesquisada sobre. Ficaria nesse estilo:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input('Digite um número: '))
        y = int(input('Digite um número: '))
        if x < y:
            exit()
        if x == y:
            exit()
    except:
        print("O valor de 'x' não pode ser menor ou igual a 'y', saindo...")
```

A função exit() automaticamente acionará o que está dentro da "except", printando assim o erro para quem está usando